# React Native Maps integration in iOS build error 'RCTPackagerClient.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Working on React Native Maps integration in iOS, getting build error as follows
'RCTPackagerClient.h' file not found, the error is shown inside npm module devpods/react/core/modules

As per the [github link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17799) adding  'DevSupport' didn't worked for me.

```
Here is my pod file 
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # Pods for testApp
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod "yoga", :path => "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]
   # React Native third party dependencies podspecs
   pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
   pod 'glog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
   # If you are using React Native <0.54, you will get the following error:
   # "The name of the given podspec `GLog` doesn't match the expected one `glog`"
   # Use the following line instead:
   #pod 'GLog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"
   pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils' # Remove this line if you don't want to support GoogleMaps on iOS
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end

target 'testApp-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testApp-tvOS
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add 'DevSupport' to your Pod file to fix the issue.

> pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => ['DevSupport']

For more information check the link below:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17799

Comment: if you check my pod file code , you can see that, its already there.

Answer (score 0):

Test using this podfile and adapt your APP name accordingly

```
 target 'YOUR_APP_NAME' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
  ]
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"

  pod 'GLog', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => "#{rn_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"

  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path 
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```